# How to prevent clicking on header column

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to prevent click event in a header column.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th class="column">Header</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="column">Body 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="column">Body 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="column">Body 3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**And my script**

```
$('.column:not("th")').on('click', function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not:

```
$('td.column').on('click', function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add tbody selector on you code

```js
$('tbody .column').on('click', function() {
  alert("test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="column">thead</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="column">thead Body 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="column">thead Body 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="column">thead Body 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tr>
    <td class="column">Header</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column">Body 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column">Body 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column">Body 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```